# Norm $N$ on $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$ is multiplicative, $N(x)$ prime $\Rightarrow x$ irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]=\{a+b\sqrt{d}\mid a,b \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ where $d$ is not divisible by the square of a prime, prove that the norm $N(a+b\sqrt{d})= |a^2-db^2|$ satisfies the assertions: $N(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$; $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$; $x$ is a unit if and only if $N(x)=1$; and if $N(x)$ is prime, then $x$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 4):

We define $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d] = \{a + b \sqrt d : a, b \in \mathbb Z\}$ where $d$ is a square-free integer.

---

**Claim**: $N(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.

**Proof**: If $N(x) = N(a + b \sqrt d) = 0$, then $N(x) = \vert a^2 - db^2 \vert = 0$ which means $a^2 = \vert d \vert b^2$. If either $a$ or $b$ are not zero, the other one isn't and we get that $d$ is not square-free, a contradiction. Conclude that $a = b = 0$ and hence $x = 0$.

Conversely, if $x = a + b \sqrt d = 0$, then $a = b = 0$ which means $N(x) = \vert a^2 - d b^2 \vert = 0$.

---

**Claim**: $N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$.

**Proof**: Let $x, y \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ with $x = a + b \sqrt d$ and $y = m + n \sqrt d$. Observe that
\begin{align*}
N(x)N(y) &= \vert a^2 - db^2 \vert \vert m^2 - dn^2 \vert \\
&= \vert(am)^2 + (dnb)^2 - \big( (an)^2 - (bm)^2 \big) d \vert
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
N(xy) &= N\big((a + b \sqrt d)(m + n \sqrt d) \big) \\
&= N\big( (am + bnd) + (an + bm) \sqrt d\big) \\
&= \vert (am + bnd)^2 - d (an + bm)^2 \vert \\
&= \vert(am)^2 + (dnb)^2 - \big( (an)^2 - (bm)^2 \big) d \vert.
\end{align*}
Conclude that $N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$.

---

**Claim**: $x$ is a unit if and only if $N(x) = 1$.

**Proof**: Suppose that $x$ is a unit, then there exists $y$ such that $xy = 1$. Observe that $$1 = N(1) = N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$$ which means $N(x) = 1$.

Conversely, suppose that $\vert a^2 - d b^2 \vert = N(x) = 1$. Choosing $y = a - b \sqrt d$, we see that $$xy = (a + b \sqrt d)(a - b \sqrt d) = a^2 - db^2 = \pm 1.$$ Conclude that $x$ is a unit.

---

**Claim**: If $N(x)$ is prime, then $x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$.

**Proof**: Suppose $N(x) = N(a + b \sqrt d) = p$ is prime (and hence irreducible since prime elements are always irreducible). Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $x$ is not irreducible, then we can write $x = yz$ where $y, z$ are not units. But then $$p = N(x) = N(y)N(z)$$ where $N(y), N(z) \neq 1$ by previous result. This contradicts that $p$ is irreducible (since the only units in $\mathbb Z$ are $\pm 1$). Conclude that $x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x=a+b\sqrt{d} \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$, consider the map $z \mapsto xz$.

Then, in the $\mathbb Z$-basis $\{1,\sqrt d\}$, this map is given by the matrix $\pmatrix { a & bd \\ b & a }$.

Noting that $N(a+b\sqrt{d}) = \det \pmatrix { a & bd \\ b & a }$ simplifies the arguments, since the determinant is multiplicative.