# The set $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: functions, algebraic-number-theory

**Note**: this is very similar to this problem [Norm on integral domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325562/norm-on-integral-domain), but I’m attempting the proof for extra practice. Idk, it might even be equivalent to the first proposition but just worded differently.

Let $d>1$ be a square free integer. Consider the set $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]= \{a+b\sqrt{d} : a, b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Prove that every element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ can be uniquely written in the form $a+b\sqrt{d}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof. Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ where $d$ is a square free integer.  Then $x = a + b \sqrt{d}$.  Next, suppose that $x = n+m\sqrt{d}$ where $a \neq n$ and $b \neq m$.  Then $a + b \sqrt{d} = n + m \sqrt{d}$, however, $\sqrt{d} \notin \mathbb{Z}$, so $b \sqrt{d} = m \sqrt{d}$, and since this is an integral domain, $b=m$.  So, $a + b \sqrt{d} = n + b \sqrt{d}$, which means that $a = n$, so we have a contradiction.  Therefore, every element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ can be uniquely written as $a + b \sqrt{d}$.